# How to colloquially refer to things written on the blackboard?

Tags: slang, reference

<sup>English text below.</sup>

Manche wunderbare Vortragende, die auf Englisch wärend der Vorlesung bzw. während des Vortrags über Mathematik u.ä. an der Tafel schreiben, sagen oft *„this guy“* anstelle des echten Namens des mathematischen Objektes (i.d.R. ist es dem Publikum langweilig oder unangenehm, eine ganze Folge mehrfach adjektivierter Nomen zu hören, wenn eine vereinfachte Version dessen –die graphische– existiert. Dafür kann man halt auf die Tafel zeigen und *this guy* sagen).

**Frage.** Was würde ein Mutterspracher, der sich mit diesen Themen gut auskennt, anstelle dessen auf Deutsch sagen? Ich denke *Objekt* ginge nicht. Denn ein Anteil des Reizes dieses Ausdrucks ist eben, dass *guy* fremd der Mathematik ist. Ginge dann *das Ding da* oder *dieses Ding*?

---

Some wonderful lecturers, in particular mathematicians, physicists and the like,  use to replace, while exposing at the blackboard, the (often very long) name of a mathematical object by the very handy expression:

> this guy (pointing to the object the blackboard).

What would a native speaker say in German? I first thought I could just say *dieses Objekt*, but then realized that part of the charm of the expression, is using a name alien to mathematics – a condition *Objekt* wouldn't satisfy. Another options which I would try are *das Ding da/hier*. I'd like somebody to confirm that it would work.

Comment: you could just say "das da/das hier" while pointing to the blackboard, but that's not what you are looking for, right? "Ding" sounds a bit wierd to me and I haven't heard it in this context, but that might be regional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mögliche Ausdrücke sind:

> das da
>   das hier
>   dieses Ding
>   dieses Gebilde
>
> dieser Ausdruck
>   dieser Term

Wobei die beiden letztgenannten mathematische Begriffe enthalten, die laut Fragestellung jedoch nicht gesucht waren. (Trotzdem sind sie in der Praxis in Gebrauch)

Definitiv falsch wäre es aber, "this guy" wörtlich zu übersetzen. Die folgenden Ausdrücke rufen beim Zuhörer Verwirrung hervor:

```
dieser Junge/Typ/Kerl/Bursche
```

Der Grund für die Verwirrung ist auch schnell erklärt: Auf der Tafel stehen keine Personen, sondern Sachen (Dinge). Es ist im Deutschen nicht üblich Dinge mit Personen-Bezeichnungen zu versehen. Die Begriffe Junge, Typ, Kerl und Bursche, die als Übersetzung von "guy" möglich sind, bezeichnen aber allesamt eine jüngere männliche Person. Diese ist auf der Tafel aber nicht zu finden.

Comment: "dieser Kerl"/"dieses Kerlchen" wird durchaus oft in dem Kontext genutzt

Comment: Genau, »der Kerl da«, das wird durchaus gesagt. Oder auch einfach »der Willi« oder »der Karl-Wilhelm« oder »der Fritze«. Oder vielleicht auch »der Hans-Hubert«! Oder »unser Freund«. Da gibt es dutzende von Möglichkeiten.

Answer (score 3):

- dieses Kerlchen hier (for variables)
- das [Trumm](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trumm_Stueck_Splitter) da (for complex terms)
- das da/das hier (for everything, clearly the winner at my university)
- das alles hier (for areas)

Answer (score 2):

Yiddish has a couple of expressions which don't seem to be suggested by our German correspondents, namely *der dasiger* and *der jeniger* , meaning obviously "this one" and "that one". The standard German equivalents would be *dieser* and *jener*, the latter being also considered good Yiddish but the former frowned on as a Germanism. And while I believe *dieser* and *Jener*  only work as adjectives in German, the Yiddish forms go both ways, as adjectives or stand-alone pronouns.

In my experience they also, when used as pronouns, have a bit of an implication of applying to people, like "that guy". So I think they are pretty close to what the OP is looking for. Also, I have the impression that *der jeniger* is a bit of a humorous counterpoint to *der dasiger*, because *jener* is a perfectly good Yiddish word.

Example of usage: In the Passover Seder's "Four Questions", the common Yiddish translation of "Why is this night different..." goes "Far wâs is der dâsiger nacht anders vun…". In general, *dieser nacht* would be frowned upon but *jener nacht* is just fine.

EDIT: I suggested above that *dieser*, unlike its Yiddish counterpart, does not double as a pronoun in German but only works as an adjective. I gained confidence in this belief because none of our other correspondents offered "dieser" as an option in the present situation. But then I stumbled upon an example of this very thing in an elementary school reader from the 1950's:

> "Hast du dein Buch auch mit ins Bett genommen?" frage Fritz den Martin nach der Schule. "Nein" sagte *dieser*, ich hab's in meinter Mütze gelegt."

So was I wrong about *dieser*? I should mention that the reader comes from Southern Manitoba's Mennonite enclave.

Comment: Yiddish is as much on topic as any other German dialect.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/686/6010) for a discussion about Yiddish on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe an dieser Stelle oft "den hier" gehört und benutzt, z.B. in der Form "wie wollen nun, dass der hier klein ist" oder "wir teilen den hier durch den hier".

Answer (score 1):

In scientific math classes at german universities (schools) you will often hear:

> " *Dieser Term* kann umgeformt werden..."

and is equal to

> "*This expression* can be transformed..."